# Clojure: Increment every item of a list/vector by its first element

Tags: clojure

My try:

```clojure
(defn inc-by-f [v]
      map #(+ (first v) %) v)
```

### EDIT

(The original question was stupid; I missed the parenthesis. I am still leaving the question, so that perhaps I learn some new ways to deal with it.)

```clojure
(defn inc-by-f [v]
  (map #(+ (first v) %) v))
```

What other cool “Clojure” ways to achieve the desired result?

Comment: `(map + v (repeat (first v)))` is quite cool i think ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing parentheses around the `map` invocation. The following works as you expect:

```
(defn inc-by-f [v]
  (map #(+ (first v) %) v))
```

Comment: @Okay, that was stupid of me. With your permission, I want to change the question. (Which means your answer will be irrelevant.)

Comment: @blackened Please don't do that. Anything that invalidates answers is a no-go. If you have another question, please post it separately.

Comment: Small issue with this - the `first` will be evaluated on **every** loop, not just once. To avoid that, either define it outside the loop with `let` or use `partial` instead of the anonymous function

Comment: @tar: agreed - I was just showing OP that the "problem" he thought he was observing was simply a matter of missing parentheses.

Answer (score 5):

"Cooler" way (answered later than https://stackoverflow.com/a/62536870/823470 by Bob Jarvis):

```clj
(defn inc-by-f
  [[v1 :as v]]
  (map (partial + v1) v))
```

This uses

- [sequential destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring#_sequential_destructuring) to extract the first element of the input vector while still maintaining a reference to the entire vector using `:as`
- [`partial`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partial) to avoid the need for an [anonymous function literal](https://clojure.org/guides/learn/functions#_anonymous_function_syntax), which increases readability in some peoples' opinion (count me in!)

Note that the vector destructuring is only useful if the increment value is in a place that is easily accessible by destructuring. It could work if the value was the "2nd in the vector" (`[_ v2 :as v]`), for example, but not if the value was "the maximum element in the vector". In that case, the max would have to be obtained explicitly, e.g.

```clj
(defn inc-by-max
  [v]
  (map (partial + (apply max v)) v))
```

Also note that anonymous functions are evaluated on each call, unlike `partial` which is handed all its arguments and then those no longer need to be evaluated. In other words, if we take the first element of a 1000-element `v` inside the anonymous function, that will result in 1000 calls to `first`, instead of just one if we get the first element and pass it to `partial`. Demonstration:

```clj
user=> (dorun (map #(+ (do (println "called") 42) %) (range 3)))
called
called
called
=> nil
user=> (dorun (map (partial + (do (println "called") 42)) (range 3)))
called
=> nil
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, as to how this answer works. For example, how would it be had the problem been `increment by the max element of the list`?

Comment: `inc-by-max` function example added, along with links to relevant documentation